# How much information, in bits, is conveyed by a 3-bit output representing how many 1s in a 7-bit input?

Tags: information-theory

Let's say I have a combinational device that has an input of 7 bits and outputs a 3-bit binary number that reflects the number of 1s among the 7 bits.
How much information would be conveyed by the following outputs: 000 and 001?
I know information, in bits, is calculated by log2(1/p), and p is M/N, where N is the number of equally probable choices, and M is the amount of choices left after being given a piece of data.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  You're going to need to provide a probability distribution on the 7-bit value.  i.e., how are the 7-bit values generated?  Are all 7-bit values equally likely?  Also, if you know all of that, it sounds like you already have an answer; what are you stuck on, and what prevents you from using what you know to answer the question?

Comment: I am having difficulty finding the probability.
Each of the 128 7-bit binary number inputs occur with equal probability. To my understanding, this does not mean that each number of occurrences of 1 is equally probable (seven 1s is less likely than three 1s).
I know the maximum number of 1s in the 7-bit value is 7. An output of 001 represents one 1 in the 7-bit value. What would be the probability of this output? Is it 1/7? And why?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the 7-bit input is chosen randomly, the entropy of the number of 1s is
$$
 \sum_{i=0}^7 \frac{\binom{7}{i}}{2^7} \log \frac{2^7}{\binom{7}{i}} \approx 2.45 \text{ bits}.
$$
This is because the probability that the number of 1s is $i$ equals $\binom{7}{i}/2^7$.

You are asking how much information is conveyed by particular outputs, and this can be interpreted as the loss in entropy: if $X$ is the random 7-bit input and $Y$ is its sum, you could define the information conveyed by $Y=i$ as $H(X)-H(X|Y=i)$. Since $X$ has uniform distribution,
$$
 H(X) - H(X|Y=i) = \log 2^7 - \log \binom{7}{i} = \log \frac{2^7}{\binom{7}{i}}.
$$
The information conveyed by different outputs, under this definition, works out to be roughly (in bits):
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
i & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\\hline
H(X) - H(X|Y=i) & 7 & 4.19 & 2.61 & 1.87 & 1.87 & 2.61 & 4.19 & 7
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
The weighted average of these values equals the entropy calculated above.